# My react-app is not Loading and not showing error

Tags: reactjs

I have created an bookshelf app using react. But when I start it, the tab is keep loading with a white screen and there is no error in the DOM showing. Please help me what to do? This is the repo link: https://github.com/Vivek-aDev/bookshelf-app

I just need to load the page first and render the content. That is it from my side.

Comment: Hi @Vivekananda. It will really helpful to us to help you, if you please provide more detial and share what you tried so far that is not working for you